# Why does this give a chain of distinct closed subsets?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

In the proof of proposition ${1.10}$ of Harsthorne (which proves that an open subset $Y$ of an affine variety ${\overline{Y}}$ have equal dimension), Harsthorne says that if ${Z_0\subset Z_1 \subset ... \subset Z_n}$ is a chain of distinct irreducible closed subsets of $Y$ then ${\overline{Z_0}\subset \overline{Z_1}...\subset \overline{Z_n}}$ is a chain of distinct irreducible closed subsets of ${\overline{Y}}$. I am aware why each ${\overline{Z_i}}$ is irreducible, but I am not quite sure why they are necessarily **distinct**. I am sure it's not hard to see why but for some reason I cannot think of why this is true. Can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: $\overline{Z_i}\cap Y=Z_i$ (really for any topological space $X$, subspace $Y\subset X$ and set $T$, the closure of $T$ in $Y$ is the closure of $T$ in $X$ intersect $Y$)

Comment: @Ariana ahhh yes I see! That makes sense. So they are distinct otherwise it would contradict the ${Z_i}$'s being distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be an irreducible topological space and $U \subset X$ an open subset. Then, the assignment $Z \mapsto \overline{Z}$ gives a bijection between the irreducible closed subsets of $U$, and those of $X$ which intersect $U$.

*Proof.* First, we note that $\overline{Z}$ is indeed irreducible (check!) and we claim that $Y \mapsto Y \cap U$ is the inverse map. By the topological property mentioned by Ariana in the comments, $\overline{Z} \cap U = Z$ so one direction is already done.

Lastly, we claim that if $Y$ is irreducible and closed, then $\overline{Y \cap U}= Y$. First $Y$ is closed containing $Y \cap U$, so $\overline{Y \cap U} \subset Y$. On the other hand, since $Y \cap U$ is a nonempty open subset of $Y$, it is dense in $Y$, so that $Y \subset \overline{Y \cap U}$. This proves the equality and hence that this correspondece is bijective.

QED

Comment: Nice.  The result is also true even if $X$ is not irreducible, right?